# sencha touch map not showing fullscreen

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch

i've declare my map

```
ChalkMobile.mapContent = new Ext.Map({
    fullscreen: 'true',
    useCurrentLocation: 'true',
    mapOptions : {
        zoom: 18,
    },
});
```

but it's not showing in fullscreen. there's a large grey area and the map covers only less than 1/8 of the screen. any idea how to fix this?

thanks. =D

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
layout: {
   type: 'fit'
},
```